# Interpolation and using time manager in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, timeslider

I have a dataset that is made of a set of points, each representing a sensor that measures air quality. The data has a location, value for emissions and time (one measurement per hour).

[image: snapshot of attribute table]

[image: snapshot of shapefile]

What I'm trying to do is visualize the area that is being measured by creating an interpolation (I was thinking of IDW) of the area for each time period. Then I would like to be able to use the time slider in ArcMap (or perhaps Qgis) to see the difference through time.

My question is how do I create an interpolation for each time period? By just applying the IDW tool on my dataset I seem to be getting a static image: I can't scroll through it using the time.